# How to block specific URIs in the Firefox source code?

Tags: c++, firefox, mozilla

I apologize, I'm new to Firefox's source code structure, and have bad English.

I want to make a compiled version of Firefox with some (hardcoded) URIs being blocked.

I was looking at the `mozilla-unified\netwerk` folder for a suitable place to block URIs, but couldn't find a good place.

Any idea about a good cpp file to place URI-blocking code?

Comment: Why do you need to hard-code the URIs in Firefox's source code itself? Why not just use the standard Firefox browser as-is, and write a custom add-on to block sites by URI? There are several add-ons already available that do this with pre-compiled builds of Firefox, so it is clearly possible.

Comment: Seems like a clumsy approach.    Better to configure your firewall to block the relevant sites - can't be undone except by users who have administrative access to configure the firewall.   Modifying a browser is a weak approach, as there is nothing preventing a user from downloading and installing an unmodified/unrestricted version of the browser.   If you must do it in the browser (and trust your user) there are browser add-ons.

Comment: The decision to modify the code and compile is taken by my client. Maybe he has a different use case and wants to future change the browser.